# How to config webhook for TFS shelveset

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, sonarqube

We use TFS shelvesets to perform code reviews in our team. Now we plan to run SonarQube to analyze our code and simplify code review.

I need to configure webhook of something else to run SonarQube. But TFS allows this for changesets but not for shelvesets. We use TFSC for version control and can't migrate to GIT to use pull request.

Does anybody solve this or similar task? How can I implement this functionality?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Extension+for+VSTS-TFS) instruction page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this extensions suits for pull request. How can I use it for shelvesets? I want not to add additional operations in current development workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot achieve that.

The changeset will be submitted when check in the changes, and CI build will be automatically triggered with the latest changeset version but not the Shelveset. And the changes with Shelveset are not really checked in, it will not trigger the CI build.

Besides, For TFVC the services (including webhook) only support `Code checked in` event, but the shelveset changes are not really checked in. See T[eam Services service hooks events](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/service-hooks/events) for details.

So, as you said TFS only allows this for changesets.

The SonarQube extension is very helpful to track the code smells, you can see [Microsoft DevOps Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/12/13/sonarsource-have-announced-their-own-sonarqube-team-services-tfs-integration/) to know about that.